# When using compass-importer and gulp fonts are not being compiled correctly

Tags: gulp, font-face, compass-sass, compass

My issue is that I'm using [`compass-importer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compass-importer) with `gulp` however my fonts are not displaying, it looks as though they are not being compiled correctly.

SASS

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Mikado-Regular";
  src: font-files("../_fonts/Mikado/mikadoregular-webfont.woff", "../_fonts/Mikado/mikadoregular-webfont.woff2", "../_fonts/Mikado/mikadoregular-webfont.ttf"); 
}
```

Compiled CSS

```
@include font-face("Mikado-Regular", font-files("../_fonts/Mikado/mikadoregular-webfont.woff", "../_fonts/Mikado/mikadoregular-webfont.woff2", "../_fonts/Mikado/mikadoregular-webfont.ttf"));
```

It doesn't appear the `font-face` mixin is being pulled in correctly. However there are no errors.

I'm wonder if it's something to do with a `config.rb` file I have (as I was using [Prepos](https://prepros.io/) previously, however there doesn't appear to be an option to include this with `compass-importer`.

What's strange is I've updated my SASS paths to be relative to the `main.css` so this `config.rb` file with the relative path shouldn't matter, I should still see the compiled `font-face` syntax and maybe even a 404 error with the browser looking for the font.

Part of my `gulpfile.js` is below:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var compass = require('compass-importer')
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

// Setup SASS
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('scss/main.scss')
    .pipe(sass({ importer: compass }).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'ie 10'))
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(sass({
            sourceComments: 'map',
            sourceMap: 'sass',
            outputStyle: 'expanded'
        }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../../public/skins/website/_css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

I've wanted to try and avoid using `gulp-compass` if possible only because I wanted to avoid installing Ruby.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You are calling `sass()` three times. I don't know if that's the cause of your problem or what you're trying to do, but that's definitely not a good idea...

Comment: @SvenSchoenung thanks, I've removed that and combined it into one hoping that might work, however I'm still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `compass-importer` doesn't process the file or include the correct mixin in the same way that using compass with ruby does.  `compass-importer` doesn't use the `config.rb` file at all.

This is the `_font-face` mixin, it doesn't include the format type syntax for other font types.

```
@mixin font-face($name, $font-files, $eot: false, $weight: false, $style: false) {
  $iefont: unquote("#{$eot}?#iefix");
  @font-face {
    font-family: quote($name);
    @if $eot {
      src: font-url($eot);
      $font-files: font-url($iefont) unquote("format('embedded-opentype')"), $font-files;
    }
    src: $font-files;
    @if $weight {
      font-weight: $weight;
    }
    @if $style {
      font-style: $style;
    }
  }
}
```

My solution is to just update all my files to include the verbose CSS, as this way it's not dependant on either `compass` or `compass-importer`.

I could change the mixin but was worried that it would be overwritten should there be an update to `compass-importer` as I still need to include this.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Mikado-Regular';
    src: url('../_fonts/Mikado/mikadoregular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../_fonts/Mikado/mikadoregular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../_fonts/Mikado/mikadoregular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../_fonts/Mikado/mikadoregular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../_fonts/Mikado/mikadoregular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../_fonts/Mikado/mikadoregular-webfont.svg#intro_bold_capsregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```